# Classic German Literature

Tags: history, book, literature

I´m looking for a book on German Literature, describing its history the differents phases and currents, something rather exhaustive and "umfangreich". Is there a classic textbook ? (like for example the 6-volume Lagarde & Michard for the French literature, or a bit like "Der Ewige Brunnen" for German poetry).

Answer (score 5):

The "standard" textbook on German literature is the [Kindlers Literatur Lexikon](https://www.metzlerverlag.de/index.php?mod=bookdetail&isbn=978-3-476-04000-8).

This exhaustive encyclopedia comes in 18 volumes and will cover everything.

For covering German literature only there is a much leaner textbook "[Deutsche Literaturgeschichte](https://www.metzlerverlag.de/index.php?mod=bookdetail&isbn=978-3-476-02453-4)" which in the only recently published 8th edition is quite up to date.

Comment: It seems to cover literature from all over the world.

Comment: you're perfectly right @Deve. I added another reference.

Comment: thx i ll check it out before I mark your answer

Comment: @Yves: dont hesitate to write your own answer if you find a book that meets your needs better.